# Assiging Random Values to an Array in C

Tags: c

```
    #include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

int i = 1;



int main()
{
   int nums[20];

   srand(time(NULL));

   while(i < 20){
        nums[i] = rand()% 10;
        i++;

   }
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", nums[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]);
}
```

when I run this code I am given values I expect, Ie under 10, except for the values for 2, 3, and 4, and more often than not 4 is negative.... Any help on what I have done wrong would be appriciated

Comment: #include <stdio.h> has also been included there

Comment: `printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", nums[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]);` could perhaps be written more clearly. In fact, I don't think the last argument makes any sense

Answer (score 3):

```
nums[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

is equivalent to

```
nums[20]
```

due to the funny [`,`-operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Try enumerating elements like this (starting with `0`):

```
nums[0], nums[1], ..., num[19]
```

And initialize `i` to `0`:

```
i = 0;
```

Or, although it is usually looks suspicious, start at `1`, but then declare

```
int nums[21];
```

Comment: And make `i` into a local variable, not a global.

Answer (score 2):

Write your last line as a loop instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    printf("%d\n", nums[i]);
```

Comment: That has got it to run as expected, do you know what it was I was doing incorrectly?

Comment: As @AlexD said, you cannot index arrays like `nums[1, 2, 3, ...]` because `(1, 2, 3, ...)` evaluates to `20`.